# Ubuntu 16: Configuring a (trunk) interface w/o IP address

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I intend to use one of my Ubuntu 16 interfaces as a trunk, so I don't need any IP configuration on that interface (it'll all be on VLAN-bound subinterfaces). How do I configure it w/o an IP address? At present it has an IP address automatically allocated to it by NFVI during VM deployment, and if I try hashing it out in /etc/network/interfces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg I get this:

```
root@client:/etc/network/interfaces.d# service networking restart
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@client:/etc/network/interfaces.d#
```

Unhashing it there clears the issue. Is there a "no ip address" of some kind?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently assigning link-local via CLI clears that error - but only when assigning IP**v6** link-local with "iface ens5 inet**6** auto". An attempt to assign IP**v4** link-local with "iface ens5 inet auto" still returns the error but I'm fine with IPv6 link-local alone anyway. It'd still have been nice to let an interface be brought up w/o any IPv4/IPv6 address whatsoever though, e.g. exactly for use as trunk.